# Load runner Ajax true client protocol script recording issue

Tags: performance-testing

We are working on the Load runner Ajax true client protocol scripting. The given flow is when we double click on a record , it will navigate to the new window. But while recording the script new window is not opening.

LoadRunner version – 12.60

How can I resolve the recording issue?

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to new window (record and replay) is working absolutely fine in current latest version of Microfocus Loadrunner 2020 https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/products/loadrunner-professional/download